# Can not append a date to a list!

Tags: python

Is there a reson why date can not append to a list?

```
vdate = str(dates.date)
vdats = vdate.split("")
vdats = vdats[0]
vbalance.append(vdats)
```

just did not work?

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE 
Error message:AttributeError: 'Decimal' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: How do you know that you can not append it? Any error message maybe?

Comment: do you get any error? what is `vbalance`?

Comment: In the future, consider expanding on what you have and what you're seeing.

Comment: sorry vbalance is just a variable

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**

I'd say the error you get is pretty self explanatory: `vbalance` is just **not a list**. So you cannot append to it.

*What is the intention of your code, what do you want to achieve?*

It might be, that you want to `add` to `vbalance`:

```
vbalance += int(vdats)
```

or that you have to create a list beforehand:

```
l = list()
vdate = str(dates.date)
vdats = vdate.split("")
vdats = vdats[0]
l.append(vdats)
```

or that you have to declare `vbalance` differently in your previous code.

---

Just from what you posted I guess you get a `ValueError`:

```
>>> string = "ab cd asd"
>>> print string.split('')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  Line 2, in <module>
    print string.split('')
ValueError: empty separator
```

Assuming `vdate` contains a valid string and `vbalance` contains a list, if you just want to split the string on the **whitespaces**, use:

```
vdats = vdate.split()
```

Otherwise you have to pass **which** separator you want to use, but obviously, this string **cannot be empty**.

**Documentation**: [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Answer (score 1):

```
vdats=vdate.split("")
```

You can't split with an empty separator. This will raise a ValueError exception.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly `vbalance` is not a `list`. Appending to a `Decimal` is meaningless, so that operation is not supported. Perhaps you meant to add `vdats` to it instead:

```
vbalance += vdats
```